# How to learn machine learning in C?

Tags: machine-learning, ai

I want to learn machine learning but I am more comfortable in C than python (also my pc is little slow), I tried to search but there are no tutorial or documentation for C. So, where can I start? Can you recommend some book or online course. Thanks for your time.

Also how realistic it would be to learn on existing tutorials does api(like of tensorflow) have any changes in python and c in variables.

Comment: if you searched and there are no tutorials, rest assured there is a reason for that

Comment: C is a low level language, most modern ML methods are not implemented in C and it would probably be difficult to port existing libraries. However you can implement traditional ML algorithms (Naive Bayes, Decision Trees, etc.) yourself in C, it's a good exercise to understand how they work.